# Memory issues introduced when updating Linux kernel version

Tags: memory, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, initrd, initramfs

I have a Linux kernel v4.19 built using Yocto Pyro that works well. I have updated to kernel v5.4 and Yocto Dunfell. **With this update I am now having issues running out of memory while uncompressing my ramdisk image during boot**.

My ramdisk image is minimal, only containing Busybox + SWUpdate + a few other minor utils, for use in a recovery scenario.

My system has 128 MB of memory.

My uncompressed ramdisk image is 41 MB.

I have these CONFIGs set as below:

```ini
CONFIG_BLK_DEV_RAM=y
CONFIG_BLK_DEV_RAM_COUNT=4
CONFIG_BLK_DEV_RAM_SIZE=65536
```

I have plenty of memory for the ramdisk image and I think I have the relevant ramdisk configs set correctly.

I am thinking there is some CONFIGs that have changed in my upgrade from kernel v4.19 -> v5.4 that I need to set?

I did not have these memory issues with kernel v4.19.

Comment: You have posted an XY problem. Correlation does not always imply causation. You need to analyze the original problem of "*running out of memory while uncompressing my ramdisk image during boot*" (which presumes that's a correct assessment of boot failure) instead of guessing it's a configuration issue with the new kernel. Have you drawn a memory map of what regions are used by each boot image?